# What should I do with the 6-character minimum for edits?

Tags: feature-request, editing

I know quite a few posts with small mistakes involving less than 6 characters, but I can't correct them without some more changes in the post, because that "at least 6 characters changed" limit.

What to do with it? I can make some invisible changes in addition to the correction, but I'd be happy to know official Christianity.SE policy about this. Would something like this (click "edit" to read invisible text here)  be OK? Is there any better option? Or can I consider it a "Christianity.SE low-ranking editor's marginal edit policy"?

Comment: See also: [How to overcome “Edits must be at least 6 characters”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81520/1438)  Note that this really is a limitation designed to solve big-city problems over on Stack Overflow.  Here, it's just a nuisance.  (Also as long as we are in beta, the reputation needed to become a full editor are _much_ lower than it will be when we graduate.  You'll be there [soon](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit).)

Comment: FWIW, I've had [my own whinge about this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82893/remove-trivial-edit-restriction). Didn't help, though. :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Be creative. Find something else to fix while you have it open. I have rarely seen a post that couldn't use at least 6 characters of touch up. Maybe they didn't link a verse or format a quote. Maybe they took a grammar shortcut you can expand on for a cleaner read.

If you really can't think of anything or don't have the time, leave a comment for the original OP to fix. Not only will the OP get notified of the comment, but any 2k+ user who comes along afterwards will have the chance to fix the mistake as well since they don't have the 6 character edit limit. Note that whoever makes the fix should then flag the comment as obsolete so it gets removed and doesn't waste future readers' time.

Answer (score 7):

It's annoying and silly. Often, if you look, there'll be something else to fix. If there isn't, you could leave a comment to the post author pointing out the error and encouraging them to fix it. Mason Wheeler suggests flagging it for moderator attention, which wouldn't have occurred to me, but he's a moderator himself so he should know what he's talking about.

Answer (score 4):

Moderators are able to make very minor edits.  If you see a problem that's too small for you to edit, you can flag it as "Other" and explain the issue, and one of us can review it and make the edit.

Comment: I'll wait a while and probably accept this answer. If I find some more things to change, I'll change it, but my question was about the other case. "Comment and wait for the OP" makes unnecessary noise in the process and is the slowest method (IMHO). Flag is easier for me (or others in similar situation) and probably for moderators too than to add invisible text to the beginning of the post.

Comment: I tend to think paging a moderator for a spelling mistake is overkill when there are ways for the community to handle this without intervention. If nothing else, leaving a comment allows either the OP or any 2k+ user who happens to read it to fix it without bringing in a diamond.